# Return a subscription data within another subscription

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

```
this.subscription1$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
        map((data1) => {
          return data1.map((data2, index) => {
            // we should return here the value, not the subscription
            return this.subscription2(index + 1).pipe(
              takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
              map((data3) => {
                return of(data3);
              })
            );
          });
        }),
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('FINAL: ', data);
      });
```

That final console shows:

> [Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable]

how could I get the other subscription data directly without getting any observable?

Answer (score 0):

Depens how you want to combine subscription2 results.
If you want to wait for all to complete you may use forkJoin

```
this.subscription1$.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
  switchMap((data1) => {
    return forkJoin(...data1.map((data2, index) =>  this.subscription2(index + 1)))
  })
).subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('FINAL: ', data);
})
```

Maybe you want `combineLatest` to watch for particular changes. Choose proper operator here according your usecase

Comment: I just need the latest data. I don't need to combine any of the results, just get the last one

Comment: also tried this but final console is not triggered

Comment: Are you sure that all subscription2 observables emits / are closed ?